# Finite groups of cyclicality index $3$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group. Let’s define the cyclicality index of $G$ using the following recurrent relation:

$$CI(G) = \begin{cases} 1 & \quad G \text{ is cyclic} \\ \max_{H < G} CI(H) + 1 & \quad G \text{ is non-cyclic} \end{cases}$$

The finite groups $G$, such that $CI(G) = 1$ are exactly the cyclic groups.

The finite groups $G$, such that $Cl(G) = 2$ are of the following three classes:

1) $C_p × C_p$, where $p$ is a prime

2) $Q_8$

3) $\langle a,b \mid a^p = b^{q^m} = 1, b^{−1}ab = a^{r}\rangle$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and $r ≡ 1 \pmod p$, $r^q ≡1 \pmod p$.

But what can be told about finite groups $G$, such that $CI(G) = 3$?

By the classification of finite abelian groups, one can see, that if $G$ is abelian, it should be either $C_p \times C_p \times C_p$ or $C_p \times C_{pq}$ or $C_p \times C_{p^2}$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Non-abelian case remains obscure to me, however I know the examples of such groups: $D_{pq}$ and $D_{p^2}$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. However, they are definitely not alone...

So, my question is:
Is there a way to fully classify all finite groups $G$, such that $CI(G) = 3$? (In a way similar to the classification of groups $G$, such that $CI(G) = 2$)

Comment: You missed $C_{p^2q}$ and $C_{pqr}$ for abelian groups (with $r$ also prime)

Comment: @Robert: by definition, the CI of both is 1.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your cyclicity index is the minimal cardinal $c$ for a generating set, and I guess that the case $c=3$ has been classified.

Comment: And the groups which direct products can also be classified: they are of the form $A\times B$, where $A$ has cyclicality index $2$, and $B$ is cyclic.